# Is my New York driver permit count as an acceptable id to fly in U.S.?

Tags: air-travel, new-york-city, driving-licenses, florida

I'm just became U.S. citizen, and I want to fly to Florida from New York next week but I don't have my U.S. passport (or U.S. passport card) yet. Can I use my driver permit to get on a plane? Some of my friends told me that the driver permit is longer acceptable to fly in U.S.. Should I bring my old passport from other country, or some other types of id, such as my student id?

Comment: In the USA, a _permit_ is usually temporary for learners and a _license_ if what you get after you have had a permit and pass the examination. A NY drivers _license_ is still acceptable. Some states' licenses do not meet standards whose enforcement has been postponed to January 2018, at the earliest. Your old passport, if not expired, will also work.

Comment: I am a dual citizen of the US and another country. I often use my foreign passport to identify myself to TSA.  If I'm not using that, I use my NY driver'slicense (most recently three days ago).

Answer (score 3):

If by driver permit you mean your New York Drivers License, then yes that is an acceptable ID.  TSA is not starting to enforce the RealID rules until January 2018.

Answer (score 2):

The TSA [identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) guidelines include the following:

> - Driver's licenses or other state photo identity cards issued by Department of Motor Vehicles (or equivalent)

All valid [New York DMV-isssued photo documents](https://dmv.ny.gov/id-card/sample-photo-documents) should qualify, including

- driver license
- learner permit
- non-driver ID
- the "enhanced" versions of the above

Your friends may be referring to the [REAL ID](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id) act, which imposes a federal standard for state-issued IDs. Even though the original law was passed in 2005, however, most states are not yet in compliance, as constitutionally the federal government cannot force states to adopt the standard. Therefore, most states have received extensions.

New York's extension expires October 2017 at this writing, but they are almost certainly going to receive an additional one. In the unlikely chance they do not, you can still use any of the other forms of ID listed on the TSA page, including your foreign passport if it is still valid.